# App to add margins to a picture

Tags: android, image-editor

There's plenty of apps that can crop a picture.

But I want to make the inverse : add margins to a picture. Do you know an App that can do that ? Preferentially with the choice of the color of margins or better : add margins that are the blurred copy of parts of the original picture.